# Missing Maven Dependencies Folder in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: eclipse, maven, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm currently attempting to configure a Maven project in Spring Tool Suite for use with Tatool. I was watching [this tutorial video](http://www.tatool.ch/tutorial/tatool-tutorial-01/tatool-tutorial-01.html) and my project is identical to his after it is created except for the fact that it is missing a Maven Dependencies folder and I am also unable to "create" new dependencies (although I can add them). What gives?

Apologies in advance for the elementary nature of this question, but I'm new at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, resolved it. The tutorial was using an old version of STS which had a "create" button in addition to the "add" button under the dependencies tab of the POM. All I had to do was add a dependency and the folder showed up.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that either:

1. Your project is not a maven project.  Right click on project -> Configure -> Convert to maven project
2. You do not have m2e installed.  Open STS dashboard, click extensions at bottom and install m2e

Comment: I have m2e installed (it shows up when I check the "Show Installed" box in the extensions section of the dashboard), but for some reason the option to convert to a Maven project is unavailable. I created the project as a Maven project, though, so that shouldn't be a problem. 

EDIT: Derp, the option doesn't show up because it already is a Maven project. The problem still persists, though.

Comment: Nevermind, resolved it. The tutorial was using an old version of STS which had a "create" button in addition to the "add" button under the dependencies tab of the POM. All I had to do was add a dependency and the folder showed up.